# React event handlers, delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, events, event-delegation

I saw some other posts on that but didn't understand.

If I have a large table, with a clickable action button in each row.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td><button onClick={this.handleClick}></button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

In jquery I would bind the event to the `<tbody>` element, as I know it have a better performance. In react, if I bind the click event directly to the button, how many handlers are actually created? Is it will be as efficient as event delegation?

I've tried using onClick on the `<tbody>` and when I access the event object in the console I see this warning:

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `altKey` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

Comment: Show the action definition of `handleClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different questions I believe.

1. Is there possibility to use delegation? Yes, you can set single event handler on `<tbody>` and check for `event.currentTarget.<some attribute to know what it is>`.
2. Why warning is shown? It's because event object is actually reused so if your handler works with Event in async way like

   ```
   handleClick(event) {
       setTimeout(() => {
           alert(event.target.id);
       }, 100);
   }
   ```

   you cannot be sure it's the same event. You should store information you need immediately and later use it

   ```
   handleClick(event) {
       let id_to_store = event.target.id;
       setTimeout(() => {
           alert(id_to_store);
       }, 100);
   }
   ```
3. why React expect us to setup explicit event handlers instead of using delegation? Is not delegation much more efficient? Not really. Once you don't [create new handler function for each element](https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd#7c44) it has really tiny overhead. But as advantage of explicit binding handler you will not worry about memory leaking because handler is delegated to *too common parent element that  lives long enough*. Is it the only reason? Nope, also handlers set explicitly fits "Virtual DOM vs real DOM comparison" better.

So you can use delegation but better not until it's real bottleneck.

Comment: and if I do use event bubbling (delegation), and bind event to the tbody. How can I pass data from the clicked row? for example, each button in a row has a unique id generated inside a loop. How can I pass event data with react?

Comment: the same as it's done in jquery world: set some attribute(better use `data-...=` notation to highlight its purpose) and read it from `event.currentTarget.attributes`